# Angular-Fullcalendar Unable to use Fullcalendar methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm using [angular-fullcalendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-fullcalendar) with my angularjs 1.6 app. The calendar renders great and overall working good. I'm using a custom date selector directive that passes a date to Fullcalendar, but when I try to use the [gotoDate](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/gotoDate) method in my directive's JS I keep getting the error $(...).fullCalendar() is not a function.

I have jQuery (v3.2.1), moment.js, angular-fullcalendar.min.js, and fullcalendar.min.js (v3.9) all loaded.

What am I missing that's preventing me from using .fullcalendar() methods?

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/moment.js?"></script>
<link href="/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.css?" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/angular-fullcalendar.min.js?"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js?"></script>
```

app.js

```
let appModule = angular.module('Events',
    [
        EventsServices,
        EventSheet,
        'angular-fullcalendar'
    ]);
```

eventsheet.html

```
<div fc fc-options="calendarOptions" ng-if="selectedDate" ng-model="eventsArr" class="fullcalendar"></div>
```

eventsheet index.js

```
<script>
$scope.$watch('selectedDate', (date, oldDate) => {
    if (!date || angular.equals(date, oldDate))
    return;

    if (date != 0 && date != oldDate) {
        if ($ && $.length) {
            $('.fullcalendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: could you show your code?

Comment: Updated the original post to include code related to the angular-fullcalendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out angular-fullcalendar does not bind the calendar object to the controller. Using code from ui-fullcalendar (which I couldn't get working with my event array), I updated the angular-fullcalendar.js to the following (see lines with comments).

```
angular.module('angular-fullcalendar', [])
.constant('CALENDAR_DEFAULTS', { // *** New ***
    calendars: {}
})
.value('CALENDAR_DEFAULTS', {
    locale: 'en'
})
.directive('fc', ['CALENDAR_DEFAULTS', fcDirectiveFn]);
function fcDirectiveFn(CALENDAR_DEFAULTS) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        eventSource: '=ngModel',
        options: '=fcOptions'
    },
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs) { // *** added attrs ***
        var calendar;
        init();
        scope.$watch('eventSource', watchDirective, true);
        scope.$watch('options', watchDirective, true);
        scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
            destroy();
        });

        function init() {
            if (!calendar) {
                calendar = $(elm).html('');
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar(getOptions(scope.options));

            if (attrs.calendar) { // *** New ***
                CALENDAR_DEFAULTS.calendars[attrs.calendar] = calendar;
            }
        }

        function destroy() {
            if (calendar && calendar.fullCalendar) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('destroy');
            }

            if (attrs.calendar) { // *** New ***
                calendar = CALENDAR_DEFAULTS.calendars[attrs.calendar] = angular.element(elm).html('');
            } else {
                calendar = angular.element(elm).html('');
            }
        }
function getOptions(options) {
            const event_source = scope.eventSource;
            let isMultiSource = false;
            Object.keys(event_source[0]).forEach(key => {
                if (key === "events") {
                    isMultiSource = true;
                }
            })

            if (isMultiSource) {
                return angular.extend(CALENDAR_DEFAULTS, {
                    eventSources: event_source
                }, options);
            } else {
                return angular.extend(CALENDAR_DEFAULTS, {
                    events: event_source
                }, options);
            }

        }

        function watchDirective(newOptions, oldOptions) {
            if (newOptions !== oldOptions) {
                destroy();
                init();
            } else if ((newOptions && angular.isUndefined(calendar))) {
                init();
            }
        }
    }
};
}
```

Using the above JS, include CALENDAR_DEFAULTS in your controller dependencies. Update your fullcalendar div to include a calendar value:

```
<div fc fc-options="calendarOptions" ng-model="eventsArray" calendar="myCalendar"></div>
```

Now you can target your calendar and use fullcalendar methods!

```
CALENDAR_DEFAULTS.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', newDate);
```